# Django Haystack Reverse URL Failing

Tags: python, django

I am currently trying to configure the most barebones possible setup for Django Haystack. In my HTML, I have a form that resolves a url using a named url pattern. Here is the HTML code.

```
<form id="search-ticket-form" class="navbar-form navbar-left dropdown" method="get"
            action="{% url "search_ticket" %}" role="search">
```

Django returns an error every time saying "Reverse for 'search_ticket' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []"

Here is the configuration in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', contact.views.home, name='homepage'),
#url(r'^blog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace='zinnia')),
url(r'^profile/', include('user_profile.urls')),
url(r'^registration/', include('registration.urls')),
url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
url(r'^contact/', include('contact.urls')),
url(r'^tickets/', include('tickets.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Here is the configuration in my tickets/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'submit_ticket/$', submit_ticket, name='submit_ticket'),
                   url(r'search_ticket/$', include('haystack.urls'), name='search_ticket')
                   )
```

The setup certainly looks fine. When I substitute include('haystack.urls') for a function based view named 'abc', the url resolves just fine. This makes me think that something is wrong with my Django Haystack setup, but the error certainly is misleading. Here is what my single Haystack view looks like:

```
class TicketIndex(indexes.BasicSearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    def get_model(self):
        return Ticket
```

I modeled this setup after the barebones example in Haystack's github repo (https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/example_project/bare_bones_app/search_indexes.py).

Any thoughts on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you actually name an included URL tree? It usually includes multiple URL patterns. Looking at [haystack.urls](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/master/haystack/urls.py) you may want to try `{% url "haystack_search"%}`.